# When I resize the page into small screen , the label control is overlapped with Text box

Tags: html, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I have given three textbox in a form .If I resize the page little bit , the label  control is overlapped with textbox and some part of the label is not visible. How can I fix this issue. I have given _layout.cs file code here with and also I have attached the employee  edit  horizontal  view html

My layout file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Vehicle Management</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />      
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" />
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/simple-sidebar.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-heading"> Menu </div>
            <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light" asp-controller="Vehicle"
                   asp-action="Index">Vehicle</a>
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light" asp-controller="Employee"
                   asp-action="Employeelist">Overview</a>
                @*<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Events</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Profile</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Status</a>*@
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</button>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                        @*<li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>*@
                        @*<li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>*@
                        @*Commended by Polachan*@
                        @*<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Dropdown
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>*@
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="container">
                <main role="main" class="pb-3">
                    @RenderBody()
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
        $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

```html
@model EmpMgt.Models.ViewModels.AddEmployee


<br />
<form asp-controller="Employee"
      asp-action="AddEmployee"
      data-ajax="true"
      data-ajax-method="POST"
      data-ajax-mode="replace"
      data-ajax-update="#content"
      class="form-horizontal"
      role="form" data-parsley-validate novalidate>

<div class="row">
    
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Employee.Name" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Address1</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Employee.Address1" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Address2</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Employee.Address2" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: In the example, it doesn't.

Comment: I have added  layout html file. When I run that employee html on that layout html , it will show  overlapping problem when I resize the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo worked:
View:

```
<br />
<form asp-controller="Employee"
      asp-action="AddEmployee"
      data-ajax="true"
      data-ajax-method="POST"
      data-ajax-mode="replace"
      data-ajax-update="#content"
      class="form-horizontal"
      role="form" data-parsley-validate novalidate>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class=" control-label " style="margin-right:10px">Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="width:60%;" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group row">

                <label class=" control-label " style="margin-right:10px">Address1</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="width:60%;" />


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group row">

                <label class=" control-label " style="margin-right:10px">Address2</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="width:60%;" />


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

result:
[image]